# Change the definition of paragraph (e.g. in org-mode)

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'd like to use `mark-paragraph` (also for movement with forward/backward-paragraph) in org-mode buffers in the same way as in other major modes, i.e. to mark a continuous region delimited by empty lines. This should apply also to headings, list items, lines starting with '#' etc. – i.e. I'd like for the purposes of paragraph editing to everything be treated as regular text.

Is this possible?

Comment: I can move through paragraphs with `M-{` or `M-}`. Doesn't that mean already it works like that (except for the addition of a list item being treated as a paragraph)?

Comment: Right - what I ment is headers, list items and comment lines should be also treated just like regular text. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the variables `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate`, and possibly also the `use-hard-newlines` function which is related (but probably not actually relevant in this case).

```el
(defun use-default-paragraph-delimiters ()
  (setq paragraph-start (default-value 'paragraph-start)
        paragraph-separate (default-value 'paragraph-separate)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'use-default-paragraph-delimiters)
```

**Edit:** Admittedly, org-mode might depend upon its paragraph definitions for more than just interactive marking and moving, so here is a more targeted approach for customising the paragraph definitions for those commands only when called interactively using their key bindings.

```el
(defmacro with-default-paragraph-definition (&rest body)
  "Evaluate body forms using the default definition of a paragraph."
  `(let ((paragraph-start (default-value 'paragraph-start))
         (paragraph-separate (default-value 'paragraph-separate)))
     ,@body))

(defalias 'my-org-mark-paragraph 'mark-paragraph)
(defadvice my-org-mark-paragraph 
  (around my-org-mark-paragraph-advice activate)
  (with-default-paragraph-definition ad-do-it))

(defalias 'my-org-forward-paragraph 'forward-paragraph)
(defadvice my-org-forward-paragraph
  (around my-org-forward-paragraph-advice activate)
  (with-default-paragraph-definition ad-do-it))

(defalias 'my-org-backward-paragraph 'backward-paragraph)
(defadvice my-org-backward-paragraph
  (around my-org-backward-paragraph-advice activate)
  (with-default-paragraph-definition ad-do-it))

(defun my-org-paragraph-overrides ()
  "Use the default paragraph definitions in org-mode
        when marking or moving by paragraph."
  (local-set-key [remap mark-paragraph] 'my-org-mark-paragraph)
  (local-set-key [remap forward-paragraph] 'my-org-forward-paragraph)
  (local-set-key [remap backward-paragraph] 'my-org-backward-paragraph))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-paragraph-overrides)
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long I got side tracked with lot's of work. This is fantastic! Thanks for the solution and the care you took for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try customising the `paragraph-start` variable. I'm not sure
what would be appropriate here, org sets it to something quite elaborate
as you see in the quoted docstring below. Setting it to the default
might work, or you could try `use-hard-newlines` as mentioned in the quote below.

> paragraph-start is a variable defined in `paragraphs.el'.
>
> Its value is
>   "\f\|[   ]*$\|\*+ \|[     ]*#\|\([  ]*\([-+]\|\(\([0-9]+\)[.)]\)\)\|[   ]+\*\)\([    ]+\|$\)\|[   ]*[:|]\|\$\$\|\\\(begin\|end\|[][]\)"
>
> Original value was "\f\|[    ]*$"
>
> Local in buffer coding.org; global value is "\f\|[   ]*$"
>
> This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
>     satisfies the predicate `stringp'.
>
> Documentation:
>   Regexp for beginning of a line that starts OR separates paragraphs.
>   This regexp should match lines that separate paragraphs
>   and should also match lines that start a paragraph
>   (and are part of that paragraph).
>
> This is matched against the text at the left margin, which is not necessarily
>   the beginning of the line, so it should never use "^" as an anchor.  This
>   ensures that the paragraph functions will work equally well within a region
>   of text indented by a margin setting.
>
> The variable `paragraph-separate' specifies how to distinguish
>   lines that start paragraphs from lines that separate them.
>
> If the variable `use-hard-newlines' is non-nil, then only lines following a
>   hard newline are considered to match.

Comment: Thank you! This was the right idea. I've accepted phils solution, just for being more explicit.